# Change a file in running kubernetes pod without a restart of pod

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to change log level in logback.xml (file) which is mounted in path (say A) using configmap inside pod from where it is linked to other path (say B) inside pod.  It can be achieved by entering pod - path B and manually make changes.  But I would like to know if there is other way. Is it possible to change file and update configmap so that it will reflect in pod?  Or any other standard way?

Answer (score 0):

You can map a ConfigMap for that. 
First, create a ConfigMap with a file entry:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configmap/

Then you can mount that ConfigMap as a volume in your pod:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#adding-configmap-data-to-a-volume

When your ConfigMap changes, the file in your pod will change as well.

Comment: Yes,  currently file is mounted using configmap.  I made required changes in the file.  I've deleted and created configmap using changed file. I've tried using kubectl apply too. It did not reflect inside pod.  Should it reflect?  Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Running `kubectl -f your-configmap.yml` will update the file in the pod. Try connecting to your pod with `kubectl exec -it << pod >> -- /bin/sh` and look at the file, it sometimes takes a couple of seconds but you should see your changes. Keep in mind that the process using that file would need to watch for changes and reload to file as needed.

Comment: Thanks for an answer.  But I have tried the same,  it didn't reflect inside pod.  It got reflected only when pod is restarted.  I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: How do you mount the volume?

Comment: @Oliver how sure are you that this is supposed to work? I have always had to restart pods before they will see new configMap data.